# Comportamiento de un Form sin borde

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-forms

Buenos dias,

Estoy creando una aplicación en Windows Forms, la cual no tiene borde.
Me gustaría saber si es posible que tenga el mismo comportamiento que un Form con borde (el efecto al minimizar, maximizar, cambiar de Form).

Actualmente estoy utilizando un botón con esta función:

```
this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
```

Funciona, pero no tiene efecto de minimizar alguno, solamente se esconde de una manera "brusca", al igual que cuando cambio de un Form a otro.

Comment: Encontré esta respuesta en so, ojalá te sirva: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24641829/formborderstyle-none-removes-the-native-open-effect-of-windows-8]

Answer (score 0):

Sin borde puedes crear una serie de botones los cuales funcionaran de manera similar, creo que debes realizar un objeto que sea tu formulario en lugar del this. 
Otra cosa que puedes intentar es darle un width y heigt en base a las propiedades de la pantalla del usuario.

Answer (score 0):

es un poco tarde pero quizás a alguien más le ayude:

```
private void BtnMaximizar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (WindowState == FormWindowState.Maximized)
        {
            WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
        }
        else
        {
            this.MaximumSize = new System.Drawing.Size(Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Width, Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Height);
            WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;              
        }           
    }

    private void BtnMinimizar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
    }
```

Comment: No te preocupes por el tiempo, gracias por tu apoyo, solamente que podrías agregar una explicación para poder entenderlo mejor